# How to use IAM role to access resources using temporary credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm using AWS IAM roles that allows an instance to have access to certain resources using temporary API credentials (access key, secret key and security token).

When I test the temporary credentials using this ruby script, it runs without any problems :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'
AWS.config(
    :access_key_id     => "MY ACCESS KEY GOES HERE",
    :secret_access_key => "MY SECRET KEY GOES HERE",
    :session_token     => "MY TOKEN GOES HERE")
s3 = AWS::S3.new()
myfile = s3.buckets['My-Config'].objects["file.sh"]
File.open("/tmp/file.sh", "w") do |f|
    f.write(myfile.read)
end
```

But when using command line to run cfn-describe-stacks I get an error:

```
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=aws_credentials.cfg
cfn-describe-stacks
cfn-describe-stacks:  Refused: The security token included in the request is invalid
```

and here is my aws_credentials.cfg :

```
AWSAccessKeyId=MY ACCESS KEY
AWSSecretKey=My SECRET KEY
AWSToken="MY TOKEN=="
```

So what am i missing here ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the CLI tools support temporary credentials.  If they did, you should be able to pass your "AWSToken" in as a command line parameter.  But according to the [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/CLTRG-common-args-api.html), it only supports passing in the access key id and secret key as parameters.

> **-I, --access-key-id** VALUE
>
> Specify VALUE as the AWS Access ID to use.
>
> **-S, --secret-key** VALUE
>
> Specify VALUE as the AWS Secret Key to use.

Comment: I think it's not yet supported because the service IAM Roles is still new (about one month old). 
I Looked in the documentation, forums, googled a lot but it seems there's no support for the moment. Any way, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy with a user-data script. For example, this snippet will grab your temporary credentials and download a resource from S3. I use it for WAR deployment.

```
# Install updates and dependencies
yum -y install ruby-devel
yum -y install rubygems
yum install -y rubygem-nokogiri
gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri aws-sdk
gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri json

# Grab credentials and parse them
CREDENTIALS=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3access)
S3_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | ruby -e "require 'rubygems'; require 'json'; puts JSON[STDIN.read]['AccessKeyId'];")
S3_SECRET_KEY=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | ruby -e "require 'rubygems'; require 'json'; puts JSON[STDIN.read]['SecretAccessKey'];")
S3_TOKEN=$(echo $CREDENTIALS | ruby -e "require 'rubygems'; require 'json'; puts JSON[STDIN.read]['Token'];")

# Download myFile
cat << EOF > /etc/getFile.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'
AWS.config(
  :access_key_id     => "$S3_ACCESS_KEY",
  :secret_access_key => "$S3_SECRET_KEY",
  :session_token     => "$S3_TOKEN")
s3 = AWS::S3.new()
myfile = s3.buckets['mybucket'].objects["myFile"]
File.open("myLocalFile", "w") do |f|
  f.write(myfile.read)
end
EOF

ruby /etc/getFile.rb
```

Drop it in your CloudFormation template and log it appropriately. It'll work like a charm. You can use [instance profiles](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-iaminstanceprofile) with LaunchConfigs and [EC2 resources](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-iaminstanceprofile) no problem. I 100% confident of this. It was in touch with AWS when their docs folks added these references to the documentation.

Comment: Nice.  To get rid of the hard-coded role, you could do: `ROLE==$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/)` and then `CREDENTIALS=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/${ROLE})`

Comment: Also, the latest AWS ruby sdk doesn't require passing in the key, secret, and token.  It will use them behind-the-scenes if an instance role is in use.  So the `AWS.config` line and credential grabbing above is no longer needed in the latest SDK.

Comment: Oh that's spectacular. I'm definitely going to update my scripts accordingly. So I can skip the credential specification entirely?