# How to pass Session Token of temporary user that is retrieved with FederatedTokenResult to AWS - Java SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I can get a [Credential](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/model/Credentials.html) from [FederatedTokenResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/model/GetFederationTokenResult.html) by querying AWS. Now, I want that credential to be used by another service to create an application stack using CloudFormation API - I can create that with using my root account which I don't want. But as I read from [GetFederationToken](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetFederationToken.html) and [Credential Page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_Credentials.html), I must must pass to the service API to use the temporary credentials.

Is it possible to do things with temporary users (given permissions) to launch a stack, creating a new Key-Pair? Any links, code snippets are highly appreciated.

Seems [ruby sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109167/how-to-use-iam-role-to-access-resources-using-temporary-credentials) provides for session tokens. How do I get it done in Java ?

At the moment I create the stack that is similar to CloudFormation given as sample with AWS SDK which does not use temporary credentials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the `Credentials`, you create a `BasicSessionCredentials` object and pass that into the constructor for the `AmazonCloudFormationClient`.  For example:

```
// Package the temporary security credentials as
// a BasicSessionCredentials object, for an Amazon S3 client object to use.
BasicSessionCredentials basicSessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
    sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(),
    sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
    sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());

// The following will be part of your less trusted code. You provide temporary security
// credentials so it can send authenticated requests to AWS CloudFormation.
AmazonCloudFormationClient client = new AmazonCloudFormationClient(basicSessionCredentials);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Is it possible to create Access Keys using these temporary credentials ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do here?

Comment: I was trying to use Cloud Formation APIs using temporary credentials and later read [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-roles.html) that CloudFormation does not support calling its API with an IAM role which is what I think is used when using Federated Tokens too. I am now using real IAM user credentials to call cloud formation API which works fine.